# SimpleDateFormat giving ParseException for unknown reason

Tags: java, simpledateformat, parseexception

I need to format my date (in Java) which is in String format. When I use the following code, taken from an [tutorial/reference source](http://www.roseindia.net/java/java-conversion/StringToDate.shtml), it just gives the following error. I have tried everything I can think of.

My code:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat ("E dd/MMM/yy");
java.util.Date date = format.parse ("12/31/2006");
System.out.println (date);
```

This results in the following error:

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "12/31/2006"

I am actually trying to format this string `"2011-7-27"` but it gave the same error, which resulted me in trying that format for the string I feed to it.

Is there anything you can see which I mess up somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you've given *isn't* taken from the page you linked to. That format string doesn't appear anywhere on the page.

You've included an "E" in the format specifier, which corresponds to the day of the week - but then you're not providing that. You've also used "MMM" as the month specifier, which would be a textual representation (e.g. "Jul"). Finally, you've specified "yy" for the year, but then given 4 digits. (This won't actually cause an issue - it'll cope with four digits - but it's better to specify the format you actually expect.) If you *just* want to give "12/31/2006" your format should be `"MM/dd/yyyy"`.

If you actually want to parse "2011-7-27" you should use `"yyyy-M-dd"` as the format string.

Comment: and MMM I believe means a 3 letter month abreviation like Jan, Feb etc. but you give 2 digits!!! Also your example date has month and day in the wrong order ... look long and carefully at your format string and you see it wants 2 digits for a DAY, 3 letters for a Month and 2 digits for a year, your date "12/31/2006" is completely bollocks.

Comment: @Angel: Yup, I covered that :)

Comment: Sorry, your more elaborated answer was not theren when I formulated mine ;D

Comment: @Angel: We need a "this post has been edited" even when one is writing a comment, it seems :)

Comment: Note: the number of characters is only important for formatting and only the month ones for parsing... `M/d/y` and `y-M-d` are as good as `MM/dd/yyyy` and `yyyy-MM-dd` for parsing. Month work differently since with 3 or more `M` the month is interpreted as text.

Comment: Guys please see how I edited Jon Skeet's answer to be the actual answer I wanted/needed. I was getting the date in String format from an outside source which was strange "2011-7-27" so I needed to be formatted to: "27 Jul 2011". I did not know the format you init SimpleDateFormat with had to correspond with the raw date you would parse with it...

Comment: @Nideo: (Thanks for the edit, btw.) Yes, that's the whole point of passing the pattern to `SimpleDateFormat`... What did you think it was going to do with it, if it wasn't going to use it for the parsing/formatting?

Comment: I thought SDF would recognize the date passed to it to parse, and then the format you specified at the beginning is the way it would output. - I was wrong ... ;-)

Comment: @Nideo: It *is* confusing that `Format` appears in its name when it can both parse and format, I'll give you that much :)